# I can extract characters but not sought-after substrings of JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JSON, but have read several of the tutorials on the web (e.g., http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/). On one page of my site I have generated an array of thumbnail images and encoded it via json as follows:

```
<?php //lots of code
$sqlTh = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT thumb FROM video WHERE status = 'active'");
$jsonTh = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlTh)){ 
    $jsonTh[] = json_encode(array($row));
}
?>
```

I then declare the global var thumbs and use document.ready(function () to call my thumbnail loading function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thumbs = '<?php echo json_encode($jsonTh) ?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadThumbs();
});
</script>
```

The function loadThumbs() is in an external file...the JSON string can be alerted and have its length displayed as follows:

```
function loadThumbs() {
    alert(thumbs); //No problem
    alert(thumbs.length); //No problem
}
```

I can see the JSON string...the alerted output looks like this:

```
["[{"thumb":"thumbnail1.jpg"}"]", etc , etc , etc }"]"]
1756 //(string length)
```

Right now all I would like to do is see each member of the string/array.....I have tried alerting the following:

```
function loadThumbs() {
    alert(thumbs[2].thumb);
}
```

but the alerted output is "undefined". I then tried solutions which use a for loop to loop through the array and set a variable for each member of the array:

```
function loadThumbs() {
    for (var i = 0, len = thumbs.length; i < len; i++) {
       var th = thumbs[i];
       alert(th);
    }
}
```

However, this alerted all 1756 characters of the array instead of each .jpg file name. Changing the function a bit to the following did not alert anything (no alert box at all):

```
function loadThumbs() {
    for (var i = 0, len = thumbs.length; i < len; i++) {
       var th = thumbs[i].thumb;
       alert(th);
    }
}
```

I know one solution would be to use the js split() function on the JSON string, but I would like to know where I am going wrong without using the split() function. Can someone shed some light on this? I would appreciate any help...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a PHP expert, but from your code I see that you are creating an array of JSON encoded string, one for each row, and then you JSON encodes the whole array, so the output you get it's what you should expect.

More over, you forgot to JSON decode the string on the javascript side.

Try to change your code as this:

```
<?php //lots of code
$sqlTh = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT thumb FROM video WHERE status = 'active'");
$jsonTh = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlTh)){ 

    $jsonTh[] = array($row);     //don't encode each row!!

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
    //use JSON.parse to re-decode on the javascript side
    var thumbs = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($jsonTh) ?>');    

    for (var i = 0, len = thumbs.length; i < len; i++) {
       var th = thumbs[i].thumb;
       alert(th);
    }
} 

</script>
```

You should get alerted all the thumbs as you expect.
Be aware that if the thumbs property are expected to contains apostrophes, you have to escape them on the js side, too.

Comment: You were right about not encoding each row.....this was part of the problem. However, adding the JSON.parse changed the JSON string to a series of members that were (literally) [object Object] instead of "thumb":"thumbnail.jpg" . I will continue to work on this.

Comment: You see the array members as [object Object] because each member is actually an object, with a "thumb" property. Try to post a comment with an extract of the JSON you get on the browser, so I can confirm this.

Comment: The code --- alert(thumbs) ---  outputs on the browser (as an alert box)  --- [object,Object], ---  27 times (where 27 is the correct number of thumbnail jpg files). The code alert(thumbs[2].thumb) outputs --- undefined --- . The function loadThumbs() is in an external javascript file (not sure if this matters).

Comment: You didn't get me... I mean: in the html page that you get in the browser, you'll have : "var thumbs = JSON.parse('[what do you get here?]');". I need to see what you get inside the []

Comment: Sorry..I misunderstood. I viewed the source in the browser: <script type="text/javascript">
var thumbs = JSON.parse('[[{"thumb":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/E3IzRqY2ko4\/1.jpg"}],[{"thumb":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/7jmKo7US0Kw\/1.jpg"}]]');
</script>    I did not include the other 25 members.

Comment: Ok, so you get an array of all rows, where each row is itself an array , with only one element which is finally the object rows, containing the thumb property.

Comment: I rewrote my php and removed the array function from the WHILE loop: <script type="text/javascript">
var thumbs = JSON.parse('["http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/E3IzRqY2ko4\/1.jpg","http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/7jmKo7US0Kw\/1.jpg"]');
</script>

Comment: Try to transform the PHP row "$jsonTh[] = array($row);" to "$jsonTh[] = $row;" This should remove the unneeded extra array. Otherwise, change the javascript to "var th = thumbs[i][0].thumb;"

Comment: Actually, just got it. I alerted thumbs[1] (with array removed as written in my last post) and saw the correct .jpg. Thanks for all of your help...definitely was a series of 'best answers'. I will mark your response as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have improper syntax:

```
["[{"thumb":"thumbnail1.jpg"}"]", etc , etc , etc }"]"]
```

Make sure the quoted are around the identifiers and the values:

```
"thumb": "thumbnail1.jpg"
```

And in your example:

```
[[{"thumb":"thumbnail1.jpg"}], "etc" , "etc" , "etc" }]]
```

Never put quotes around braces or brackets…

`DON'T DO THIS:  "[" "]" OR "{" "}"`

Good luck with JSON!

Comment: I don't generate the array manually nor do I place the quotes anywhere. The alerted output is what I wrote. The array (set equal to var thumbs) is an associative array generated from a mysqli_query from my site's database. In other words, what I wrote is what json_encode on the associative array is outputting.